# How do I unlearn an enchantment?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

I use [Enchanting Awakened](http://skyrim.nexusmods.com/mods/42796/?) mod, but we are supposed to only be able to learn new enchantments (thru disenchanting), when we have the appropriate perks...

The problem is, I also use the [Frostfall](http://skyrim.nexusmods.com/mods/11163/?) mod, that lets me have a portable enchanting equipment. But that equipment does not have the enchanting table script that prevent me from learning enchantments.

So I am trying to find a way to fix my game..

If I save the game like `save test 1` it generates a text file where I can read all learned enchantments:

```
ENCHs:

  0010EAD1    17/17    00000001  74 Corpus: Channeled Alteration            - Flags(6)                 
  0010FB96    17/17    00000001  74 Corpus: Frost                           - Flags(6)                 
  0010FB7D    17/17    00000001  74 Aether: Aetherflux                      - Flags(6)                 
  0010FB75    17/17    00000001  74 Chaos: Destruction                      - Flags(6)                 
  0010FB97    17/17    00000001  74 Aether: Spellstrike                     - Flags(6)                 
  0010FB9A    17/17    00000001  74 Soul Trap                               - Flags(6)                 
  0010FB74    17/17    00000001  74 Aether: Conjuration                     - Flags(6)                 
  0010FB99    17/17    00000001  74 Aether: Lightning (Rank I)              - Flags(6)                 
  0010FB95    17/17    00000001  74 Chaos: Fire                             - Flags(6)                 

Total ENCH Count: 9  Total ENCH Size: 153/153 - Data: 54/54 Overhead: 99 Debug: 0 Min ENCH Size: 17  Max ENCH Size: 17  Average ENCH Size: 17.00
```

I wonder if I could remove such entries and recreate the savegame?

I found this tool: [Save Cleaner](http://skyrim.nexusmods.com/mods/31724/?tab=1&navtag=%2Fajax%2Fmoddescription%2F%3Fid%3D31724%26preview%3D&pUp=1), but I am not sure if it can handle learned enchantments. As soon I have time, I have to play with it to see what happens! Feel free to try and report too! Are there any other useful tools to accomplish this goal?

**How do I unlearn an enchantment?**

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about mod development.  Mod development questions are on-topic for the Game Dev stack exchange though, so you can try asking there.

Comment: subscribed thx! well, it is about how to fix a savegame, and indeed this may have better acceptance at game dev! here is more for questions about the normal gameplay right? at most already available console commands I guess? and not for creating solutions; I've been asking questions at this stackexchange, and here is the only one I usually initially get many downvotes lol.. must be because I am a coder, and so I initially think that way, I ask for unavailable solutions to be created so ppl think together :)

Comment: @bwarner I don't think this is about mod development at all. OP wants to unlearn an enchantment. He tried console commands (`save test 1`) and have found a tool (Save Cleaner) that may help in doing so but he is not sure how he could use those to help in his goal. Those are just background research.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After searching around, this is what I found (from [UESP wiki "Skyrim - Enchanting" article talk page post by user Is404](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim_talk:Enchanting#Unlearning_.2F_Removing_Learned_Enchantments_From_Table_List)):

"After much research on 'unlearning' enchantments, the general assumption that is is not possible is incorrect. It is not possible to do through a console command, and requires an ESS File Editor to modify the content of the save-file.

When in the ESS File Editor, find the entries in the `Change forms` list (between `Global data table 2` and `Global data table 3`) designated by `ENCH`. These are your learned enchantments, though the nested information my not be all that useful. I'm not sure how to tell which enchantment is which, but I would assume they're either alphabetized or listed in order learned. To unlearn all enchantments, delete all `ENCH` items from the list and save. It is recommended to make a backup beforehand.

Why would anyone ever want to do this? I had an issue with a learned enchantment not showing up in the available enchantment list while unable to re-learn the enchantment from another item. I suspect this was due to a save error due to an alt-tab crash to desktop, but it's anyone's guess. There are a few posts here and there of others having this problem or otherwise interested in 'unlearning' or removing listed enchantments. There was even a post in this page's discussion mentioning a method of editing hex in the game's memory (which I couldn't seem to make work).

I was able to purge my save-file of all learned enchantments and am spawning in items with the previously learned enchantments. One thing to note is that the item spawned in must be a game-item with the enchantment already on it (ex: Dwarven Warhammer of Absorption [000acc70] = Absorb Health), not one that you've enchanted via the console (ex: `playerenchantobject 0001397E 000aa155 1` will not work)."

An [ESS File Editor for Skyrim](http://skyrim.nexusmods.com/mods/27119/?) can be downloaded [here](http://skyrim.nexusmods.com/mods/27119/?). The mentioned [method of editing hex in the game's memory is here](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim_talk:Enchanting/Archive_3#Unlearning_an_enchantment).

Comment: thx bro, this seems promising! gotta try as soon I can! also, about the alt+tab problem, check [SBW](http://skyrim.nexusmods.com/mods/4/?)

Comment: I found all `ENCH` with the ending (last 2 hexas like `EAD1`) of the IDs I listed, match the IDs I can read at `ESS File Editor`. So I can remove them individually based on that; but on my case I need to remove all so will be even easier! I loaded the savegame and all my learned enchantments are gone! with [this list](http://forums.nexusmods.com/index.php?/topic/462434-all-enchant-recipes-via-disenchant/page-2) I can re-add only the items I had learned enchantments and try to drag them to my house (lol) for later disenchant when I have the proper perks; (I tested and I can re-learn them) thx!